# what is the difference between return and break in python?

Tags: python, function, loops

what is the difference between return and break in python?
Please explain what they exactly do in loops and functions?
thank you

Comment: Read up on [flow control](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) in the Python docs.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`break` is used to end a loop prematurely while `return` is the keyword used to pass back a return value to the caller of the function. If it is used without an argument it simply ends the function and returns to where the code was executing previously.

There are situations where they can serve the same purpose but here are two examples to give you an idea of what they are used for

#### Using `break`

Iterating over a list of values and breaking when we've seen the number `3`.

```
def loop3():
    for a in range(0,10):
        print a
        if a == 3:
            # We found a three, let's stop looping
            break
    print "Found 3!"

loop3()
```

will produce the following output

```
0
1
2
3
Found 3!
```

#### Using `return`

Here is an example of how `return` is used to return a value after the function has computed a value based on the incoming parameters:

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a+b

s = sum(2, 3)
print s
```

Output:

```
5
```

#### Comparing the two

Now, in the first example, if there was nothing happening after the loop, we could just as well have used `return` and "jumped out" of the function immediately. Compare the output with the first example when we use `return` instead of `break`:

```
def loop3():
    for a in range(0, 6):
        print a
        if a == 3:
            # We found a three, let's end the function and "go back"
            return

    print "Found 3!"

loop3()
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: We may add a key function to this simple example: If you have a `while` in a `while` loop `break` will exit to the parent loop while `return` will end both loops directly. This could come in handy when you need precise control of your execution flow and omit code in the parent `while` when finding sth. in the inner `while`.

Answer (score 20):

[`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) is used to end loops while [`return`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) is used to end a function (and return a value).

There is also [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) as a means to proceed to next iteration without completing the current one.

`return` can sometimes be used somewhat as a break when looping, an example would be a simple search function to search `what` in `lst`:

```
def search(lst, what):
    for item in lst:
        if item == what:
            break

    if item == what:
        return item
```

And nicer, equivalent function, with `return`:

```
def search(lst, what):
    for item in lst:
        if item == what:
            return item # breaks loop
```

Read more about simple statements [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html).

At the instruction level you can see the statements do different things:

`return` just returns a value ([`RETURN_VALUE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-RETURN_VALUE)) to the caller:

```
    >>> import dis
    >>> def x():
    ...     return
    ... 
    >>> dis.dis(x)
      2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
                  3 RETURN_VALUE
```

`break` stops a the current loop ([`BREAK_LOOP`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-BREAK_LOOP)) and moves on:

```
>>> def y():
...     for i in range(10):
...         break
... 
>>> dis.dis(y)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              21 (to 24)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 7 (to 23)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          19 BREAK_LOOP          
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   23 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             27 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 9):

`return` would finish the whole function while `break` just make you finish the loop

Example:

```
def test_return()
    for i in xrange(3):
        if i==1:
            print i
            return i
    print 'not able to reach here'


def test_break()
    for i in xrange(3):
        if i==1:
            print i
            break
    print 'able to reach here'

test_return()  # print:  0 1
test_break()  # print:  0 1 'able to reach here'
```

Answer (score 0):

Return will exit the definition at the exact point that it is called, passing the variable after it directly out of the definition. Break will only cause the end of a loop that it is situated in.

For example

```
def Foo():
    return 6
    print("This never gets printed")

bar = Foo()
```

That will make bar equal to six. The code after the return statement will never be run.

The break example:

```
def Loop():
    while True:
        print("Hi")
        break

Loop()
```

That will print only once, as the break statement will cause the end of the infinite while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at an example:

```
def f(x, y):
    n = 0
    for n in range(x, y):
         if not n % 2: continue
         elif not n % 3: break
    return n
print((f(1, 10)))
```

This prints `3`. Why? Let's step through the program:

```
def f(x, y):
```

define a function

```
    n = None
```

set variable 'n' to `None`

```
    for n in range(x, y):
```

begin iterating from 'x' to 'y'. in our case, one through nine

```
         if not n % 2: continue
```

discontinue this iteration if 'n' is evenly divisible by two

```
         elif not n % 3: break
```

leave this iteration if n is evenly divisible by three

```
    return n
```

our function 'f' "returns" the value of 'n'

```
print((f(1, 10)))
```

'f(1, 10)' prints three because it evaluates to 'n' once execution leaves the scope of the function

Answer (score 0):

I will try to illustrate it with an example:

```
def age_to_find_true_love(my_age):
    for age in range(my_age, 100):
        if find_true_love_at(age):
            return age

        if age > 50:
            break

    return "...actually do you like cats?"
```